# ASP.net jQuery dialog does not finish post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple example view with two (slightly different) links, one with an inline confirm and one that uses JQuery to show a dialog. They should both end up in the same place, and they both appear to properly hit the controller events. The inline action works just fine and we re-direct to the result page on a positive response. The jQuery / JavaScipt event also hits the controller and I've even traced it into the render for the result page but nothing actually renders out to the screen.

Now, the only thing that I'm doing a little strange is the hidden field to store the url to the Result Action, but storing it like this seems to the correct thing to do to avoid issues with the URL being improperly read by JavaScript.

Dialog.cshtml:

```
@using System.Globalization
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dialog";
}

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

<h2>Dialog</h2>

<p><a href='@Url.Action("Result")' onclick="return confirm('Are you really sure?');">Click Me</a></p>

<button type="button" id="TestLink">Show JQuery Dialog</button>

<input type="hidden" id="RouteUrl" value='@Url.Action("Result")' />

<div id="dialog" title="jQuery UI in ASP.NET MVC">
    <p>You now have the power of ASP.NET, the simplicity of client-side scripting with jQuery, and the looks of jQuery UI.  Congrats, web slinger!</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // This code runs on page load
    $(function () {

        // Attach a 'dialog' action to the dialog div above
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 450,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                     var url = $("#RouteUrl").attr("value");
                    $.get(url);

                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        // Show the dialog when the show-dialog click event fires
        $("#TestLink").button().click(function (e) {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCWorkbench.Controllers
{
    public class JavaScriptController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Dialog()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Result()
        {
            return View();
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly.  Are you trying to browse to the url when you click the OK button in the dialog box, or are you trying to load the data from the Dialog ActionResult and place it in the dialog box?

Based on your code it looks like you are trying to browse to the page after hitting OK in the dialog box.  If that is so, instead of using

```
$.get(url);
```

use:

```
window.location.href(url);
```

jQuery is retrieving the data from the server but you are currently not doing anything with it.

Comment: Humm, that helps some, it now consistently works on IE but Chrome is throwing an error: Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function (line 38) all that seems to be there is $(this).dialog("close"); .... ????  That error seems to indicate that I'm missing a ';' ?